# How to configure XMPP to allow all logged in user to see each other and chat with each other?

Tags: xmpp

I am new to XMPP.
I am using Openfire server, and created a console client using Smack library.

**My usecase:**
All users anonymous, logged in (In future, website visitors) will be able to see other anonymous, logged-in users. And they can initiate a private chat (one-to-one) with any of them.

So, I am able to logged in as Anonymous user, but I am not able to see other Anon / Logged in users (using Roster), because they are not in anon user's roster.

So, What should be configuration OR custom=component/code to to achieve this usecase?
Do I need to create server component? Any hint? **OR**
It can be done using proper configuration?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Multi chat room MUC, and join users after login to this room.After user joins muc room they can get paricipiants list.

Comment: I did the same. But forgot to post the solution here.. Thanks. :-)